# Backbone render view multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a backbone.js app where I have a view like:

```js
var StoreView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: ".container",
initialize: function() {
    this.render();
},

events: {
    "click #addProduct": "addProduct",
},

render: function() {
    this.$el.html(render("index"));
},

addProduct: function(){
    var productView = new StoreProductView({
        el: $('#products')
    });
    productView.render();
}
});
```

and my `StoreProductView` looks like:

```js
var StoreProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
render: function () {

    this.$el.html(render("products/product"));

    return this;
}
});
```

So when I click #addProduct, a new `StoreProductView` template is called. But if you hit #addProduct again, nothing happens. How can I get it so that for each time #addProduct is hit, a new `StoreProductView` is rendered? So if I hit it x number of times, there is x `StoreProductView`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change this line:

```
this.$el.html(render("products/product"));
```

to this for example:

```
this.$el.append(render("products/product"));
```

because every time you substitute the html and nw you don't append, only remove html content and insert the new one.
With `append()` you can add anoter product.